# XPath required: How to retain child XML tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML

```
<root>
    <somecontent name='xyz'>
        <some>PQR</some> 
        (XYZ)
        <class>something</class>
    </somecontent>
</root>
```

And I am trying to get following output in a string variable

```
<some>PQR</some>  (XYZ) <class>something</class>
```

I tried number of xpath but all of them returned 
`PQR (XYZ) something`

I want to retain the child tag as well for further processing.

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you are currently using to set the variable? Thanks!

Comment: XPath does not deal with tags at all. It only selects nodes (elements, text nodes, etc.) from a tree. The element nodes can be *serialized* using tags, but that is outside the scope of XPath. This may seem like a pedantic distinction, but it's fundamental to what you can do and how you can do it in XPath.

Comment: Are you really looking for a string as output? If so, you're asking for code to serialize XML into a string. In other words, do you want your variable to contain the string `'<some>PQR</some> etc.'` (which is unusual in XSLT and would require more work), or do you want it to contain element and text nodes (the natural way to do things in XSLT)?

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/somecontent/node()
```

**To see what is selected, use**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/*/somecontent/node()"/>
```